# Express Vue not creating association, userId is null

Tags: postgresql, express, vuejs2, vuex

I am following this tutorial using Express.js Postgres and Vue to create a CRUD app for Songs with login and basic associations : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipYlztBRpp0

I am using Vuex to manage the state object. However, for some reason, though registration of new users works to create a user record, when I try to create a Bookmark, which essentially pairs a UserId with a SongId, UserId is always recorded as null. SongId is saved correctly. Checking the requests in the network and Vue tabs of developer tools reveals that the User object seems to be empty.

Here are the relevant files.

```
User.js model
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt-nodejs'))

function hashPassword (user, options) {
  const SALT_FACTOR = 8

  if (!user.changed('password')) {
    return;
  }

  return bcrypt
    .genSaltAsync(SALT_FACTOR)
    .then(salt => bcrypt.hashAsync(user.password, salt, null))
    .then(hash => {
      user.setDataValue('password', hash)
    })
}

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    hooks: {
      // beforeCreate: hashPassword,
      // beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
      beforeSave: hashPassword
    }
  })

  User.prototype.comparePassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, this.password)
  }

  return User
}
```

Songs model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Song = sequelize.define('Song', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    artist: DataTypes.STRING,
    genre: DataTypes.STRING,
    album: DataTypes.STRING,
    albumImageUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    youtubeId: DataTypes.STRING,
    lyrics: DataTypes.TEXT,
    tab: DataTypes.TEXT
  })

  return Song
}
```

Bookmark's controller:

```
const {Bookmark} = require('../models')

module.exports = {
  async index (req, res) {
    try {
      const {songId, userId} = req.query
      const bookmark = await Bookmark.findOne({
        where: {
          SongId: songId,
          UserId: userId
        }
      })
      res.send(bookmark)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occurred trying to fetch the songs'
      })
    }
  },
  async post (req, res) {
    try {
      const {songId, userId} = req.body
      const bookmark = await Bookmark.findOne({
        where: {
          SongId: songId,
          UserId: userId
        }
      })
      if (bookmark) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: 'you already have this song bookmarked'
        })
      }
      const newBookmark = await Bookmark.create({
        SongId: songId,
        UserId: userId
      })
      res.send(newBookmark)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occurred trying to create the bookmark.'
      })
    }
  },
  async delete (req, res) {
    try {
      const {bookmarkId} = req.params
      const bookmark = await Bookmark.findById(bookmarkId)
      await bookmark.destroy()
      res.send(bookmark)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occurred trying to delete the bookmark'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

BookMarksService (for axios connection)

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  index (bookmark) {
    return Api().get('bookmarks', {
      params: bookmark
    })
  },
  post (bookmark) {
    return Api().post('bookmarks', bookmark)
  },
  delete (bookmarkId) {
    return Api().delete(`bookmarks/${bookmarkId}`)
  }
}
```

and the component SongsMetaData:

```
<template>
  <panel title='Song Metadata'>
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <div class="song-title">
          {{song.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="song-artist">
          {{song.artist}}
        </div>
        <div class="song-genre">
          {{song.genre}}
        </div>
        <v-btn
          dark
          class="cyan"
          :to="{
            name: 'song-edit',
            params () {
              return {
                songId: song.id
              }
            }
          }">
          Edit
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          v-if="isUserLoggedIn && !bookmark"
          dark
          class="cyan"
          @click="setAsBookmark">
          Bookmark
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          v-if="isUserLoggedIn && bookmark"
          dark
          class="cyan"
          @click="unsetAsBookmark">
          UnBookmark
        </v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <img class="album-image" :src="song.albumImageUrl" />
        <br />
        <div class="song-album">
          {{song.album}}
        </div>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </panel>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
import BookmarksService from '@/services/BookmarksService'

export default {
  props: [
    'song'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      bookmark: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'isUserLoggedIn'
    ])
  },
  watch: {
    async song () {
      if (!this.isUserLoggedIn) {
        return
      }

      try {
        this.bookmark = (await BookmarksService.index({
          songId: this.song.id,
          userId: this.$store.state.user.id
        })).data
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    async setAsBookmark () {
      try {
        this.bookmark = (await BookmarksService.post({
          songId: this.song.id,
          userId: this.$store.state.user.id
        })).data
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    async unsetAsBookmark () {
      try {
        await BookmarksService.delete(this.bookmark.id)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.song {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.song-title {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.song-artist {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.song-genre {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.album-image {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: none;
  height: 600px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}
</style>
```

and the vuex store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ],
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    isUserLoggedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken (state, token) {
      state.token = token
      if (token) {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
      } else {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      }
    },
    setUser (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setToken ({commit}, token) {
      commit('setToken', token)
    },
    setUser ({commit}, user) {
      commit('setUser', user)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please show code of your vuex store

Comment: Added vuex store.js file above.